# Xcode 6 simulator has multiple iphone6 and 6+ entries

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xcode6

[image]

Hopefully, the image explains the problem. Why are there 2 entries each for 6 and 6 Plus? And better yet, how can I clean this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps to clean it :

```
1. Tap on Xcode - Open Developer Tool - iOS Simulator
2. On iOS Simulator, tap on  Hardware - Device - Manage Device

Here you will found list of all devices with multiple entries. Select any device, on right click you will found option to delete it. You can also add new device from here.
```

Comment: Thanks! That was too easy…and should've been obvious to me.